# How do you query a database using a Date and Time from PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

How do I fix my query code so that it searches the database using a Date and Time but the Date is a variable from the function? I am new to PHP and SQL and don't know how the Dots ( `.` ) and Quotations fully work ( `"" ''` ). How do i fix this piece of code?

```
WHERE Fixture.date => '$FixtureDate 00:00:00' AND Fixture.date =< '$FixtureDate 23:59:59'
```

Please See code below

```
function FSearchDate($FixtureDate) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=DATABASE_NAME", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $statement = $conn->query("
        SELECT Fixtures.fixtureid AS FixtureID, 
        Fixtures.date AS Date, 
        Fixtures.week AS Week, 
        Fixtures.home_team AS HomeTeam, 
        Fixtures.away_team AS AwayTeam,
        FixtureScores.home_team AS HomeScore, 
        FixtureScores.away_team AS AwayScore
        FROM Fixtures
        INNER JOIN FixtureScores ON Fixtures.fixtureid=FixtureScores.fixtureid 
        WHERE Fixture.date => '$FixtureDate 00:00:00' AND Fixture.date =< '$FixtureDate 23:59:59'"
        );
        $result = $statement->fetch();

        if ($result == null) { // Fixture ID Doesn't Exist
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The Fixture ID entered is not valid. Please enter a valid Fixture ID");</script>';
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['FixtureID'] = $result[0];
            $GLOBALS['FixtureDate'] = $result[1];
            $GLOBALS['FixtureWeek'] = $result[2];
            $GLOBALS['FixtureHomeTeamName'] = $result[3];
            $GLOBALS['FixtureAwayTeamName'] = $result[4];
            $GLOBALS['FixtureHomeTeamScore'] = $result[5];
            $GLOBALS['FixtureAwayTeamScore'] = $result[6];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "An problem occured: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;
}
```

Comment: try your query without the `FSearchDate()` method, does it work? If so, it's a variable scope.

Comment: Please consult a tutorial on PHP & MySQL integration. The "dots" are for string concatenation, and the quotation types (' vs ") matter, especially in the context you're using them.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong:

```
WHERE Fixture.date => '$FixtureDate 00:00:00' AND Fixture.date =< '$FixtureDate 23:59:59'"
```

You're trying to use the `=>` and `=<` which don't do what you expected.

The `=>` is the separator for associative arrays.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Those should read as `>=` and `<=` respectively, as in "more than or equal to" and "less than or equal to".

**Note:** `=<` doesn't exist and isn't a valid operator/separator.

Say it out loud: ***"less than or equal to"***. We never say "equal to or less than".

Plus, *you may have* a variable scoping here for the `FSearchDate()` method, where you would might have to pass the database connection to. Yet, this might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use here `between`

```
$statement = $conn->query("
    SELECT Fixtures.fixtureid AS FixtureID, 
    Fixtures.date AS Date, 
    Fixtures.week AS Week, 
    Fixtures.home_team AS HomeTeam, 
    Fixtures.away_team AS AwayTeam,
    FixtureScores.home_team AS HomeScore, 
    FixtureScores.away_team AS AwayScore
    FROM Fixtures
    INNER JOIN FixtureScores ON Fixtures.fixtureid=FixtureScores.fixtureid 
    WHERE Fixtures.date BETWEEN 'date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$FixtureDate)' AND 'date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$FixtureDate)'"
    );
```

check this statement,

```
WHERE Fixtures.date BETWEEN 'date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$FixtureDate)' AND 'date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$FixtureDate)'
```